# Python subparser parsing with nargs='+'

Tags: python, argparse

I have to make a parser with command line arguments like this

```
python function.py -v 1 name1 -d abc xyz foo bar name2 -i 3 -p abc xyz
```

I did this:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.add_argument('-v', type=int, help='number')

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help', dest="command")
parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('name1', help="name1 help")
parser_a.add_argument("-d", help="list", nargs="+")

parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('name2', help="name2 help")
parser_b.add_argument("-p", help="list2", nargs='+')
parser_b.add_argument("-i", help="number inside name2", type=int)
```

When I run this:

```
parser.parse_args('-v 1 name1 -d abc xyz foo bar name2 -i 3 -p abc xyz'.split())
```

It results in:

```
usage: PROG [-h] [-v V] {name1,name2} ...
PROG: error: unrecognized arguments: -i 3 -p abc xyz
```

And when running this:

```
parser.parse_args('-v 1 name1 -d abc xyz foo bar name2'.split())
```

It results in this:

```
Namespace(command='name1', d=['abc', 'xyz', 'foo', 'bar', 'name2'], v=1)
```

I want it to be something like this:

```
Namespace(command='name1', d=['abc', 'xyz', 'foo', 'bar'], command='name2', p=['abc', 'xyz'], i=3, v=1)
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Two problems: only one subparser can be invoked at a time (as the first positional argument for the main script), and even if you could invoke multiple ones, theres no way to tell where the arguments to the `-d` option end. Is `name2` a positional argument or an argument for `-d`?

Comment: name2 is supposed to be a positional argument. If it is not possible this way, is there any other way this can be done?

Comment: You could use this workaround: https://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2010/08/08/python-argparse-combine-nargs-with-subparsers/

Answer (score 1):

As you note

```
In [24]: parser.parse_args('-v 1 name1 -d abc xyz foo bar name2'.split())
Out[24]: Namespace(command='name1', d=['abc', 'xyz', 'foo', 'bar', 'name2'], v=1)
```

`name2` is seen as one of the arguments to `parser_a` `-d` argument

The rest ' -i 3 -p abc xyz' is not accepted because `-i` is understood to be an optional flag.

Effectively you are running:

```
In [28]: parser_a.parse_args('-d abc xyz foo bar name3 -i 3 -p abc xyz'.split())
usage: PROG name1 [-h] [-d D [D ...]]
PROG name1: error: unrecognized arguments: -i 3 -p abc xyz
```

The main parser has a positional argument that accepts 2 choices, `name1`, and `name2`.  When it encounters `name1`, it passes the rest of the arguments to `parser_a`.

The net effect is that `argparse` accepts only one subcommand.

I have discussed some ways around this in previous SO questions.  The sidebar found one:

[Python argparser repeat subparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114652/python-argparser-repeat-subparse)

(that may be a good enough fit to mark this question as a duplicate).

---

If I add a positional to `parser_a`; and use `--` to separate `bar` and `name2` (meaning, all that follows is positional)

```
In [32]: parser_a.add_argument('extra',nargs='*')
Out[32]: _StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='extra', nargs='*', const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)

In [33]: parser.parse_args('-v 1 name1 -d abc xyz foo bar -- name2 -i 3 -p abc xyz'.split())
Out[33]: Namespace(command='name1', d=['abc', 'xyz', 'foo', 'bar'], extra=['name2', '-i', '3', '-p', 'abc', 'xyz'], v=1)
```

I can then pass the `extra` string (minus `name2`) to `parser_b`:

```
In [34]: args=_
In [36]: parser_b.parse_args(args.extra[1:])
Out[36]: Namespace(i=3, p=['abc', 'xyz'])
```

Admittedly this a convoluted solution, but the ones I suggested a couple of years ago aren't much better.  And hopefully it helps clarify what is going on.

---

Do you really need to invoke 2 subcommands at a time.  `argparse` would be a lot simpler if you could do:

```
python function.py -v 1 name1 -d abc xyz foo bar
python function.py -v 1 name2 -i 3 -p abc xyz
```

In other words, call the script twice.  That is easy if each call to `function.py` performs an independent self contained action - with any connection between the two calls embodied in shared files or database.  That is how subcommands are often used.  Trying to put multiple subcommands in one call does not save typing.

Comment: Actually the original command was:
```python function.py -v 1 name1 name2```
where name1, name2 are the sub-modules to run.

Now I want those to accept command line arguments as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing something wrong.
First you should pass positional arguments, and then keyword arguments, e.g.

```
python myapp.py arg1 arg2 --kwarg1=1 --kwarg2 val1 --kwarg2 val2
```

Comment: argparse is more flexible; it can handle mixed positionals and flagged ones.  But in this case he's also using `subparsers` when introduces its own parsing constraints.

Comment: @hpaulj i mean that subparsers is overkill in this case